# Doctrine2 mapping of association with properties

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How to effectively map the objectified(or nested) relationship for the following case.

http://i.imgur.com/yiCYh4i.png

If i have a study program i want to have all the students following any course in a certain year without having to loop over all the students in study programs. Having entities:

```
Studyprograms

Students

Courses
```

And the relation entities:

```
StudyprogramsStudents

StudyprogramsStudentsCourses
```

In this case it is important:

```
One student can have more study programs

One student follows the studyStudentCourse in a certain year.

Courses are not directly related to study programs neither to students;
```

Thanks in advance.